# Regex for word not between parentheses

Tags: php, sql, regex

Given a string, match everything that occurs after the first occurrence of a word. The word must not appear anywhere inside a pair of parentheses, but other words may. For example:

```
SELECT
t1.col1,
(SELECT t2.col1 FROM table2 t2
    WHERE t2.id IN(SELECT * FROM table5 WHERE id = t2.id)
) AS alias1,
t1.col2
----------
FROM
table1 t1,
(SELECT id FROM table3 t3 WHERE t3.id = t1.table3_id) t3,
table4 t4
```

I'm looking for everything AFTER the dotted line - specifically, everything after the 1st appearance of the word `FROM` which does not appear anywhere within a pair of parentheses

If Regex won't do, I'll craft a PHP statement to parse.  I'm having a tough time with that as well, tho!  I guess to do this, I would have to tokenize the string by word AND by parentheses?

Comment: Cant be done for the general case with a regular expression; those cant count and therefore cant tell you at what point after an opening bracket it is closed again. i dont know whether sql supports extensions to regular expressions that allow that, though.

Comment: I will consider crafting a PHP function, having a tough go at that too!

Comment: You could go about it like so: scan the string for FROM starting from the first letter. Keep a counter for the depth of nesting, initialized at 0. Whenever a bracket opens, increase it; when a bracket closes, decrease it (by 1). whenever the counter != 0, just scan characters until the counter is 0 without checking for FROM. once you have the first occurrence of FROM, take the substring starting from there.

Comment: your suggestion looks good - having trouble figuring out how to do just that ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a regex might not be the best solution here, as they can be notoriously difficult (or impossible) when nested parens are involved.

I also think looping through each character is not the best approach, as it will result in a lot of unnecessary loops.

I think this is best approach:

Find each occurance of a given string and count the number of parens before that occurance. If the number of opening parens is equal to the number of closing parens, then you have the correct match. This will result is way less looping and you're only checking what you really mean to check.

I made a function `findWord` that takes this approach. It works with your example where `$in` is your SQL statement and `$search` is `'FROM'`.

```
function findWord( $in, $search ) {

    if( strpos($in, $search) === 0 ) return $in;

    $before = '';
    while( strpos($in, $search, 1) ) {
        $i = strpos($in, $search, 1);
        $before .= substr($in, 0, $i);
        $in = substr($in, $i);

        $count = count_chars($before);

        if( $count[40] == $count[41] )
            return $in;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I'll give this method a test. I like the concept of targeting the specific $search, but it certainly seems to come at the expense of clarity. Ultimately, performance SHOULD be a non-issue due to the average SQL statement length. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @rmirabelle How about an upvote if you liked the concept? ;) Anyway, I'll go through and add some commenting later today to better explain the function.

Comment: upvote earned - tested and working - performance is about 2x my script below on a medium sized SQL chunk. Though both are negligible: .0001 vs .0002

Comment: I'm specifically confused by the offset of 1 in the calls to strpos.

Comment: The offset is for loops after the first one. Since we're cutting off from the start of `$in` up to the each occurrence `$search`, `$in` always starts with `$search` after the first loop. Without the offset, `strpos` will always match at the first character.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going with a programmatic approach unless someone has a better answer.

```
/**
 * Find the portion of the SQL statement occurring after
 * the first occurrence of the word 'FROM' (which itself
 * does not appear within parens)
 */
public static function sql_after_from($sql) {
    $arr = str_split($sql);
    $indent = 0;
    $out = '';
    $start = 0;
    $len = count($arr);
    for($x=0; $x < $len; $x++) {
        $c = $arr[$x]; //current character
        if($c == '(') $indent++;
        if($c == ')') $indent--;
        $out .= $arr[$x];
        //do the last 4 letters spell FROM?
        if(substr($out, $x-3, $x) == 'FROM') {
            if($indent == 0) { //not anywhere within parens
                $start = $x+2;
                break; //go no further 
            }
        }
    }
    //everything after the first occurrence of FROM
    return substr($sql, $start);
}
```